# X509SecurityToken is missing under Namespace of System.IdentityModel.Tokens

Tags: security, validation, exchange-server, identity, jwt

I have installed Nuget package of "JSON Web Token Handler For the Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5" (link:- http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/) for visual studio 2012. But it doesn't contains a definition for "X509SecurityToken". Which cause to show errors in following method...

```
   private static void ValidateToken(string Token)
   {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience = "<some url>",
            IssuerSigningTokens = new List<X509SecurityToken>() { new X509SecurityToken(
           X509
           .LocalMachine
           .My
           .Thumbprint
           .Find("112233445566xxyy", false)
           .First()) },
            ValidIssuer = "https://my-issuer.com/trust/issuer",
            CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
            RequireExpirationTime = true
        };

        try
        {
            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(Token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

If anyone can provide any help or even hints I would greatly appreciated,

Thanks for helping,
Kushan Randima.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add an reference to System.IdentityModel.